# How does a Xamarin.forms Android app opens in all the android versions?

Tags: xamarin.forms, android-emulator

I developed an Xamarin cross platform app and when I tried to check it on the emulator Android 8.0 - API 26 and Android 7.1 API 25 its working fine ,so I generated an .apk file and when i tried to open it on  OS 7, emulator is Genymotion for Android , I am getting an alert box stating that "app.android keeps stopping ,close app " In the visual studio in android properties I selected the minimum target version as Android 5.0 (API Level 21-Lollipop) and target Android version as use compile using SDK version .

Please help me to resolve this Issue.

Thanks

Comment: have you checked the device logs?

Comment: android device log is empty ,can you please let me know the use of device log in this case?